# Infinite loop while filtering a HashMap

Tags: rust, hashmap

```
let filterd_voxels: Vec<_> = voxel_array
    .keys()
    .filter(|n| n.x == voxel.0.x && n.z == voxel.0.z)
    .collect();
```

I am trying to get all the voxels above and below the current voxel in the for loop. It is infinitely iterating with n as it doesn't get consumed. I tried to fix it with `collect()` but I might be using it wrong?

My `voxel_array` consists of:

```
HashMap<
    Position { x: u8, y: u8, z: u8 },
    Voxel { id: u8 },
>
```

The ultimate goal of this is to check if the current voxel is the bottom one on this x,z location in the chunk. (Note: I do not mean the bottom of the chunk (y: 0) as that goes further down then the voxels in the HashMap.)

Comment: What you started with is most certainly not an infinite loop (unless your hashmap somehow has infinite keys).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up using this:

```
    let x = voxel.0.x;
    let z = voxel.0.z;
    let maybe_min_y = (MIN..=MAX)
        .filter(|&y| voxel_array.contains_key(&Position { x, y, z }))
        .next();

    if maybe_min_y.unwrap() == voxel.0.y {
        continue;
    }
```